# Циклическая ссылка в сайте на hostinger.com.ua

Tags: php, хостинг

Я создал сайт у себя на локалке. OS Windows, сборка денвер либо openserver. Всё работает.
Создал аккаунт на **[hostinger.com.ua](http://www.hostinger.ru/)**, скопировал базу (хотя до неё дело не доходит).
В итоге пишет: циклическая ссылка.

У меня реализовано mvc в `index.php`. Если убираю всё и ставлю типа `echo 111111;` - работает. То есть в моём коде, который локально работает, что-то не то.

Пробовал на других хостингах - там этой ошибки нет, зато есть другой геморрой.
В общем, так и не могу никуда мой долгожданный сайт выложить.
Подскажите, в чём дело? Ну или, может, посоветуете другой бесплатный хостинг?

Comment: КО: Все дело в твоем коде. В нем ошибка.

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: хотя бы дали ссылку на сайт, посмотрели бы.

По ходу дела - есть ли в Вашем коде js, который делает редирект или в php коде что то вида "echo Location:"?

Comment: Штатные телепаты в отпуске. Приведите, пожалуйста, код index.php

Answer (score 1):

Бесплатные хостинги вообще вещь нестабильная, там всегда урезают конфиги php, и дело, скорей, в них, а пожаловаться или предъявить претензию хостеру вы навряд ли сможете.